# GMT time and mysql NOW() is giving 2 minutes difference

Tags: php, mysql, gmt

When i was checking the GMT time [**`here`**](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/current-time/) it was **05:40:00**, at the same time i ran the below query in mysql,

```
SET time_zone='+00:00'; // to get GMT time
SELECT NOW();
```

It was **05:37:50** from above query. So in mysql i am getting around 2 minutes time difference from **[GMT](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/current-time/)**. It has to give **05:40:00** instead of **05:37:50**. How to resolve this?

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: What does the server computer clock tell you?  Is it the same difference (adjusting for the time zone)?

Comment: @GregD- in server time also i am getting 2 minutes difference.

Comment: Then look at @mvp answer.  You need to sync the time between your server and the outside world.  What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this on my Linux box.

Most likely that machine that MySQL server is running on does not have properly configured time service.

Depending of what OS your MySQL is running, you should setup time sync. For Linux, it would we ntpd package.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, can we get the exact GMT time without adjusting the mysql server time.

Comment: I think it is close to impossible to do without having reliable exact time source to begin with. You really should just fix NTP and that would fix all your problems

Comment: MySQL server takes time from the computer.  If you set your computer time correctly - it will solve MySQL time as well.

Comment: ok fine. I dont have privilege to change the time that's why asked.anyway i'll ask the network admin to change the time.